# Dynamodb local web shell does not load

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, web, amazon-dynamodb, localhost

I am running DynamoDB locally using the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html). To remove potential docker networking issues I am using the "Download Locally" version of the instructions. Before running dynamo locally I run `aws configure` to set some fake values for AWS access, secret, and region, and here is the output:

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************fake]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************ake2]:
Default region name [local]:
Default output format [json]:
```

here is the output of running dynamo locally:

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:   false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:   true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *
```

I can confirm that the DynamoDB is running locally successfully by listing tables using aws cli

```
$ aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
{
    "TableNames": []
}
```

but when I visit http://localhost:8000/shell in my browser, this is the error I get and the page does not load.
[image]

I tried running curl on the shell to see if I can get a more useful error message:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/shell
{
"__type":"com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#MissingAuthenticationToken",
"Message":"Request must contain either a valid (registered) AWS access key ID or X.509 certificate."}%
```

I tried looking up the error above, but I don't have much choice in doing setup when running the shell merely in the browser. Any help is appreciated on how I can run the Dynamodb javascript web shell with this setting.

Software versions:

`aws cli: aws-cli/2.4.7 Python/3.9.9 Darwin/20.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off`

`OS: MacOS Big Sur 11.6.2 (20G314)`

Comment: I can reach  http://localhost:8000/shell on my mac with ur setup. U dont need HTTPS for localhost. Seems like u have issues with aws  creds configuration. Check ur keys + region. Check if creds are correct in `.aws` folder  mainly in files `credentials` and`config`

Comment: I have setup the keys per instructions, they can be anything since it's local

Comment: u r right. Since its local u can have dummy config. I used dummy config. I am still able to get to shell using this. $ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: 1234556789
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: 987654321
Default region name [us-west-2]: 
Default output format [None]:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

DynamoDB Local Web Shell was deprecated with version 1.16.X and is not available any longer from 1.17.X to latest. There are no immediate plans for a new Web Shell to be introduced.

You can download an old version of DynamoDB Local < 1.17.X should you wish to use the Web Shell.

**Available versions:**

```
aws s3 ls s3://dynamodb-local-frankfurt/
```

**Download most recent working version with Web Shell:**

```
aws s3 ls s3://dynamodb-local-frankfurt/dynamodb_local_2021-04-27.tar.gz .
```

*The next release of DynamoDB Local will have an updated README indicating its deprecation*

Comment: You can download it without aws cli using this link.
https://dynamodb-local-frankfurt.s3.amazonaws.com/dynamodb_local_2021-04-27.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

As I answered in [DynamoDB local http://localhost:8000/shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690592/dynamodb-local-http-localhost8000-shell/) this appears to be a regression in new versions of DynamoDB Local, where the shell mysteriously stopped working, whereas in versions from a year ago it does work.

Somebody should report it to Amazon. If there is some flag that new versions require you to set to enable the shell, it isn't documented anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Reported it here future reference 
https://repost.aws/questions/QUHyIzoEDqQ3iOKlUEp1LPWQ#ANdBm9Nz9TRf6VqR3jZtcA1g

Comment: Someone from AWS gave an official answer on another duplicate question. It turns out that "DynamoDB Local Web Shell was deprecated with version 1.16.X and is not available any longer from 1.17.X to latest. There are no immediate plans for a new Web Shell to be introduced.", and that "The next release of DynamoDB Local will have an updated README indicating its deprecation". You can use an older version of DynamoDB Local if you want to keep using the web shell.