# DynamoDB local http://localhost:8000/shell

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm having trouble to open AWS dynamoDB shell (UI). Did anyone tried and worked?

**Steps taken:**

1. Download latest - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html
2. Start local dynamodb - No Errors
3. run `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000` - No Errors (shows the table)

**Error:**
When trying to access -> http://localhost:8000/shell i am getting `HTTP 400 Request must contain either a valid (registered) AWS access key ID or X.509 certificate.`

Ref for `shell` (UI) https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sweet-treats-for-dynamodb-users/

Note: I'm having aws cli setup with named profiles. I even tried http request in browser after exporting AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_DEFAULT_REGION and still get above HTTP 400 error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamodb local web shell does not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535330/dynamodb-local-web-shell-does-not-load)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in new versions DynamoDB Local, but I couldn't find any documentation about it being deliberate, so please try reporting it to Amazon...

I just checked version 1.13.5 from 2020-10-13, and the "/shell" works as expected and documented. But on version 1.18.0 from 2022-1-10, it doesn't - and reports the same error you listed:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 08:06:18 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0
x-amzn-RequestId: 4f040110-4464-48dc-99c1-9b843c25db5f
Content-Length: 173
Server: Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)

{"__type":"com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#MissingAuthenticationToken","Message":"Request must contain either a valid (registered) AWS access key ID or X.509 certificate."}
```

The release notes in DynamoDB Local doesn't mention anything about the shell being deliberately disabled.

You are not the first person to notice this problem - see also this question from two weeks ago:
[Dynamodb local web shell does not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535330/dynamodb-local-web-shell-does-not-load)

Comment: same. shell on browser:localhost:8000 not up, though the command is showing the output.

Comment: Someone from AWS gave an official answer on that other question I linked above. It turns out that "DynamoDB Local Web Shell was deprecated with version 1.16.X and is not available any longer from 1.17.X to latest. There are no immediate plans for a new Web Shell to be introduced.", and that "The next release of DynamoDB Local will have an updated README indicating its deprecation". That answer also includes links to older versions of DynamoDB Local, should you want to use an older version with the web shell.